# iis7 integrated mode asp.net 4.0 forms authentication problem using IE8

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, forms-authentication

Anyone experience any issues with IIS7, integrated mode forms authentication while using IE8?  I have a website with a login form, once logged in, any postback causes the user to be logged out.  This doesn't even happen consistently, sometimes I can login and not experience this issue, other times it happens instantly.  I can not replicate the problem in any other browser and I cannot replicate on my development machine running / debugging vs2010.

Comment: stupid question: are cookies enabled on the browser?

Comment: in that scenario, wouldn't it always fail?  IE8 is running under Medium trust in the Internet zone.

Comment: To clarify..login works fine on my localhost host when testing in IE8 using VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application on a server farm?  If so, ensure your web.config's have matching machine keys - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=VS.100).aspx